# NTFS specification support in Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, ntfs, specifications

I recently came across this statement:

> "...even WinXP does not completely implement the NTFS spec."

Is this true? If so, what is missing and should anyone even care? Or is this just specification stuff that just isn't (yet) needed?

Comment: Where did you come across that statement?

Comment: 2nd comment here: http://superuser.com/questions/229563/windows-xp-how-to-delete-files-that-cannot-be-deleted/229569#229569

Comment: Here is a new feature in Windows 7 and NTFS...http://www.windows7hacker.com/index.php/2010/07/ntfs-self-healing-is-an-overlooked-but-useful-feature-in-windows-7/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/pl-PL/w7itproinstall/thread/d476d983-5b63-477a-aa03-f3ac4b7973aa

> Windows Vista introduced Transactional NTFS, NTFS symbolic links, partition shrinking and self-healing functionality[8] though these features owe more to additional functionality of the operating system than the file system itself.

NTFS Versions
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS#Versions

Not much on the version 6.0 used in Windows 7

The biggest change using NTFS is TxF, Transactional NTFS, started with Vista.

Video
http://video.app.msn.com/watch/video/msdn-webcast-the-revolutionary-windows-vista-transactional-ntfs-txf-infrastructure/qm0s7fhr

.

MSDN Article
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163388.aspx

.

Another feature of TxF, explains when files suddenly go missing.

http://www.windows7hacker.com/index.php/2010/07/ntfs-self-healing-is-an-overlooked-but-useful-feature-in-windows-7/

Comment: The main thing to take away from this is that ntfs is still-evolving as a technology, and therefore of course not all versions of windows implement all the features.

Comment: "though these features owe more to additional functionality of the operating system than the (NTFS) file system itself."

Answer (score 3):

The only things that are missing are features created and implemented after XP shipped, such as symlinks.