# Can't delete a folder in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

How can we Delete a folder in windows 7 which shows "path does not exist" message when delete it?
please give a solution..

Comment: Language you are using?

Comment: thanx.i'm a newer to this site...

Comment: Here are a number of solutions to delete problems: http://superuser.com/questions/229563/how-to-delete-files-and-folders-that-cannot-be-deleted

Comment: A restart of the system can sometimes cure this error.

Answer (score 1):

You can test [this](http://download.cnet.com/Unlocker/3000-2248_4-10493998.html) program if you see the folder in explorer. It works for all kinds of situations of locked files and folders.

Answer (score 1):

I'll say you forgot to escape the `\` in your language. So for example in C, C++ and C# this `"C:\Windows"` is wrong. This `"C:\\Windows"` is right (and in C# `@"C:\Windows"` is right too)