# Cannot delete a file on Windows XP

Tags: windows, windows-xp, windows-explorer

I have a file sitting on my Windows XP desktop for about 6 years now. Its 0 bytes and every time I try to either rename or delete it, I get these error messages. Any idea how to remove this stinker completely?

As you can see its a *.torrent file and for some reason its owned by system? Which is bizzare in itself.

[image]

[image]

Here's another problem when I open the dir and DOS and look for that file. It isn't there. Yet I see it in windows explorer. I am logged in as a System Admin on my XP machine with full rights. So where is this file coming from and why its being shown when its not there?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Try stopping any/all torrent services before you try deleting the file.

Comment: Try everything mentioned [here](http://superuser.com/questions/229563/how-to-delete-files-and-folders-that-cannot-be-deleted?rq=1). If that doesn't work, update your question to let us know what you have tried. http://superuser.com/questions/229563/how-to-delete-files-and-folders-that-cannot-be-deleted?rq=1

Comment: @sawdust there are no torrent services running. Actually I had removed all torrent software from this machine years ago. As you can see it doesn't know what icon to show for *.torrent file

Comment: @Tyler look at my updated answer. I couldn't run any of the dos commands as I couldn't see the file in that folder

Comment: Keep going...you've got a few more things from the other Super User [Answer](http://superuser.com/questions/229563/how-to-delete-files-and-folders-that-cannot-be-deleted?rq=1) to try, such as running `chkdsk`

Comment: Do `dir /ah` or `dir /as` show the file?

Comment: @Brian yup, that showed the hidden *.torrent file

Comment: Per the instructions for #1 here (https://www.raymond.cc/blog/reset-system-and-hidden-attributes-for-files-or-folders-caused-by-virus/), try running `attrib -H -S` on the file. If it seems like it might've worked, then try deleting it.

Answer (score 1):

Files and folders you can't delete and can't see by some methods, which mis-report their size, or which come back after deletion are a hallmark of malware.  Many modern malware packages ("infections") contain multiple files created by multiple programs that restore each other and start each other if you manage to kill/delete one or another; these are often named in imitation of legitimate Windows files and services, making them nearly as difficult to identify "by eye" as they are to kill manually.  I'd recommend you start by running a least two different reputable malware removal tools -- ideally at least one based on a Linux Live CD (like Kaspersky Rescue Disk, as one example) -- and continue to cycle through the set until all report clean consecutively (this strategy has worked for me in the past for tough nuts like FBI Moneypak -- which was the final decider for me to abandon Windows entirely).

Longer term, I'd strongly recommend abandoning Windows XP in favor of Windows 7 (still available from some vendors, in some versions) or any comfortable flavor of Linux (many machines that can't run Windows 7 due to inadequate resources run very well with the right Linux distro; I have a 1998 vintage laptop with Pentium II 300 MHz and 288 MB RAM that runs usefully on antiX 13.2).  With XP coming on a year past end of life, yet sharing many of the vulnerabilities of newer Windows versions, you're risking major losses by continuing to run an unsupported, insecure OS; the malware resident on your system (assuming I'm correct) could steal personal information leading to identity theft, as well as make your computer part of a distributed attack system for major hacking crimes.

Comment: Are you serious? There's certainly many other possibilities besides malware for the issues OP is experiencing. Malware is a valid possibility, but there's really no need for the FUD in the second paragraph.

Comment: @luolimao Are *you* serious?  Sounds like you're saying he should keep using an OS that isn't supported any more, and thus is vulnerable, instead of switching to a secure one.

Comment: I'm saying that's irrelevant to the question, and if they wish to continue using XP then that's their prerogative. I see no reason for anyone to get malware under normal computer usage.

Comment: With "normal computer usage" I had two separate FBI Moneypak infections (verified clean after the first) on my XP system in the year before I dropped Windows in favor of Linux.  XP can no longer be made secure; even performance-sapping malware monitors can't fully protect a system that can't receive security patches.