# Cannot Delete VSHiveStub

Tags: windows, windows-10, visual-studio

I've tried everything! This file is made of titanium! It is located at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE!

Things I've tried!

-Changing the owner (Access Denied)

-Uninstalling visual studio

Giving Users the permission to delete this folder (Access Denied)

Comment: Check out the answers here and let us know how that goes: https://superuser.com/questions/229563/how-to-delete-files-and-folders-that-cannot-be-deleted